# Derivative of an infinite series of functions equal to sum of the derivatives?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, infinity

Suppose we have a series of functions $$\sum_{x=0}^\infty  h(\theta, x)$$

The question is: is it correct that $$\partial _\theta \sum_{x=0}^\infty  h(\theta, x)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty  \partial _\theta h(\theta, x)$$

I would assume that the following arguments are correct:
Take first the sequence not to $\infty$ but to $n$
$$\partial _\theta \sum_{x=0}^n h(\theta, x)=\sum_{x=0}^n \partial _\theta h(\theta, x)$$

We already know that this holds. Now simply take the limit as $n\to \infty$. We see then that the desired result is correct, so long as for each $x\in \mathbb N$, $\partial _\theta h(\theta, x)$ exists, and if the sequence $\sum_{x=0}^n \partial _\theta h(\theta, x)$ converges.

---

However, my textbook says that we need additional assumptions. We need $\partial _\theta h(\theta, x)$ to be continuous, and we need the series $\sum_{x=0}^n \partial _\theta h(\theta, x)$ to "converge uniformly".

**Why do we need these additional assumptions and what is wrong with my (sketchy) proof?**

Comment: @bof, So I'm making the assumption without justification that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \partial _\theta \sum_{x=0}^n h(\theta,x)=\partial _\theta \lim_{n\to \infty}  \sum_{x=0}^n h(\theta,x)$? This is where the problem is?

Comment: If so, how would one go about proving that under those conditions in the textbook, this condition holds?

Comment: This equivalence is a concealed form of swapping of limits, which cannot be done blindly.